# wpf as service, only active when cursor to top, sliding "taskbar" (show only when needed)

Tags: c#, wpf

Oke, so I'm looking to create a program which will not be visible until you move your mouse to the top of the screen.

I want it to come down like the taskbar (if you hide your task bar it'll slide up when you have your cursor on the position where it's supposed to be)

The nicest way I can think of is that the program won't be visible in the task bar until I drag something to the top of my screen.

I have no idea if there's a plugin to get the behaviour I want (showing it when I get near it)  or if I need to create that function my self, I also have no idea how to hide something from the task bar until it is used.

I do have an idea on how to keep it hidden from the taskbar, which would be a service which always runs (so no window) then when the mouse gets to the top of the screen it calls the wpf application and runs it. but maybe there's a better way to do it.

I have done some searching for task bar like behaviour but it came up empty, I do not have anything to show since I don't know how to start, sorry for that.

Comment: This question appears to be too broad but this might point you in the right direction. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part I've used this in the past but not sure on integration with WPF.

Comment: Nice article, it was just what i needed, i can figure stuff out my self from here, if you make it a full answer i'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CodeProject -- C-does-Shell-Part](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part)

You can use the following P/Invoke commands:

```
// Sends an appbar message to the system. 
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 SHAppBarMessage(
    UInt32 dwMessage,         // Appbar message value to send.
    ref APPBARDATA pData);    // Address of an APPBARDATA structure.                         
                              // The content of the structure depends on the 
                              // value set in the dwMessage parameter. 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct APPBARDATA
{
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    public IntPtr hWnd;
    public UInt32 uCallbackMessage;
    public UInt32 uEdge;
    public RECT rc;
    public Int32 lParam;
}

// The RegisterWindowMessage function defines a new window message that is
// guaranteed to be unique throughout the system. The message value can be
// used when sending or posting messages. 
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 RegisterWindowMessage(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    String lpString);    // Pointer to a null-terminated string that
                         // specifies the message to be registered.
```

These allows sending appbar messages to the system and controlling the state of your toolbar. See the link for more detailed information.